Unable to create a model collection in sagemaker
I would like to "Create a Collection" of models in the model registry in AWS Sagemaker. I am trying to follow this guide from AWS but am not able to get very far as I cannot see any "Collections" tab in Studio Classic. It simply does not exist so not sure what this guide is referring to. Do I need to get a newer version of studio classic somehow?


Have you tried updating your Studio version?
